# Is this a varistor?

Tags: capacitor, identification, varistor

Can someone id this green part? Z5V 104Z 500V I think maybe it's a varistor (like the blue one in the lower-right of the image) but haven't been able to find a replacement.

[image: Z5V 104Z 500V (varistor?)]

Comment: That is a capacitor, the varistor is the blue disk on the right-hand-side of the picture.  (The thingies with the single black line are \$0 ~\Omega\$ resistors :-)

Comment: What's the DC PS voltage(s) reading(s), both before and after the regulator(s)?

Comment: And does that relay (KLT1C12DC24) pull in? It should make an audible click when it does.

Answer (score 7):

It's a Z5V dielectric 500V 100nF ceramic capacitor.  Depending on how/where it's used (across the AC line or line-chassis) it may need to be a safety-rated X or Y capacitor so you will have to replace it with the correct type of capacitor if it's in one of those locations. Usually X and Y caps are film caps, but ceramics are possible too.

Comment: @Spiff -- no -- the OEM badly chintzed out.  This is a 120 or 240V piece of equipment, correct?  Also, what *is* it?

Comment: Can you trace out what this cap is connected to and get back to us @Spiff?

Comment: Why do you think it is bad? Disk ceramic capacitors are noted for having a long life (many decades). BTW, what you show in the photos is a DC power supply.

Comment: I agree with @MikeWaters that the cap may not be bad- How did you test it?  In any case it sounds like it might be an X or Y-cap, I can see that one end of it looks like it's attached to the AC line, can't tell if the other end is neutral or earth ground.  If that's the case then you can't just use any 500V 100nF cap, it has to be safety rated for the application.

Comment: @Spiff OK, you could be right about the cap being damaged.

Comment: @Spiff - I also own one of those testers. Were both leads long enough to be clamped **in a correct pair of contacts**? That could produce those readings. Also, I've seen hundreds of those capacitors with the coating broken off near the leads. And to answer your question about the DC power supply on that corner of the board, those diodes are part of what told me it was. :-)

Comment: @Spiff OK, l'll take your word for it. *However, you could probably take that capacitor off the board and it likely would still run.* That aside, testing all the parts (that you are *able* to test) is NOT the way to troubleshoot it. The first logical thing would have been to measure the AC and DC voltages. I suggest to take a course in basic electronics troubleshooting, friend.

Comment: @Spiff Understood! Time spent doing something you enjoy is not wasted time. :-)  As for taking a course, just watching a few online videos might be enjoyable. Khan Academy (https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/circuits-topic/circuits-resistance/v/circuits-part-1) comes to mind. I know there's many others on YouTube and elsewhere, most free. Learning can bring one great joy.

Comment: It's probably a long shot, but try resoldering the negative lead on the 50v electrolytic. It looks like it could be a cold solder joint.